# UIWebView and WKWebView stall on broken resource link

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a webview that loads html content with broken resource link(s) ( ie `<img src = someBrokenLink>` ) This webview will eventually load all the other contents, but it takes about 15 seconds or so.

I used the Web Inspector and noticed the webview retries 15 times to get that image source. I guess after 15 times it stops retrying and loads the rest of the webview.

This happens in both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView`. Since the webview still eventually loads, there's no error in the delegate callbacks.

Does anyone know of a way to stop the webview from retrying? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with `UIWebView` by implementing `NSURLProtocol`. I intercepted those bad links and dropped them. The webview now loads a lot faster.

`NSURLProtocol` is not supported with `WKWebView`, however, so this solution won't work for `WKWebViews`.